# Displaying a boolean matrix as a black&white image on linux terminal in c++

Tags: c++, linux, graphics

I have created a basic 2D matrix class in c++

```
class Board
{
public:
    Board(size_t xLen, size_t Ylen);
    Board(Board& board);
    Board& operator=(const Board& board);
    ~Board();
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, Board& board);
private:
    bool* m_board;
    size_t m_yLen;
    size_t m_xLen;
};
Board::Board(Board& board)
{
    m_board = new bool[board.m_yLen * board.m_xLen];
    m_yLen = board.m_yLen;
    m_xLen = board.m_xLen;
    for (int i = 0; i < m_yLen * m_xLen; i++)
        m_board[i] = board.m_board[i];
}

Board& Board::operator=(const Board& board)
{
    if (&board == this)
        return *this;
    if (m_yLen != board.m_yLen || m_xLen != board.m_xLen)
        throw std::Exception("(" + std::to_string(m_xLen) + "," + std::to_string(m_yLen)\
 + ") board can't be assigned into a (" + \
        std::to_string(board.m_yLen) + ',' + std::to_string(board.m_xLen) + ") board");

    delete[] m_board;
    m_board = new bool[board.m_yLen * board.m_xLen];
    m_yLen = board.m_yLen;
    m_xLen = board.m_xLen;
    for (int i = 0; i < m_yLen * m_xLen; i++)
        m_board[i] = board.m_board[i];
    return *this;
}

Board::~Board()
{
    delete[] m_board;
}
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, Board& board)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < board.m_yLen; y++)
       for (int x = 0; x < board.m_xLen ; x++)
            os << board(x, y) << " \n"[x == board.m_xLen - 1];
       
    return os;
}
```

I have added the implementation for recreatability.

I want to change the << operator so that matrix indexes with true value will be printed as white squares, and black suqares for the false ones.

for example:

0 1 1 0 0

1 1 0 1 1

0 0 1 0 1

1 1 1 0 1

Would translate to:

[image]

How can i do that?

I know implementing it using a GUI library like OpenGL or ImGui is possible but i rather avoid those as much as possible.

Comment: I know that this code `" \n"[x == board.m_xLen - 1]` looks very smart, but you should really avoid doing that.  The newline character can be added after the inner loop exits, without wasting time testing the value of x for every iteration.

Comment: You can change the background color for each character (since these are your  "pixels") and print spaces.  .Look here for VT color codes https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5329247/How-to-change-text-color-in-a-Linux-terminal